# Bloco de informação de quem postou está excedendo a largura

Tags: bug, layout

Nas perguntas e respostas, o bloco de informação sobre a pessoa que postou, em alguns casos o conteúdo ultrapassa a largura do bloco

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembro que houve algo similar a isso discutido aqui mas não sei como procurar para ver se é um assunto duplicado.

No outro tópico que vi, meses atrás, parece que era relacionado a quantidade de pontos e medalhas. Mas nesse caso parece não ter relação pois verifiquei rapidamente outros usuários com muitas medalhas e pontos e não apresentam o mesmo problema.

[É incorreto mudar os argumentos em uma classes estendida no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174414)

Comment: Espere passar o Winter Bash pra ver se continua assim.

Comment: Imagino que pode ser isso. Vamos esperar.

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4814/3635 (possivelmente o mesmo problema que voltou)

Comment: Com o término do winter bash o problema foi embora. Em Dezembro tem mais rsrs